# How do I configure Google storage access on Heroku project

Tags: python, heroku, google-cloud-storage

I've tried a lot of ways to get access to my HDrive but always fault!
What am I doing wrong?

```
 try:

    credentials_raw = os.environ.get('HDRIVE_GOOGLE_JSON_KEY')
    service_account_info = json.loads(credentials_raw)
    project = service_account_info.get('project_id')
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
except Exception as er:
    print(f'Error to get Google Key access : {er=}')
else:
    print(f'Google access granted! {credentials=}')

try:
    drive_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)

except Exception as er:
    print(f'Error to get Google Key access : {er=}')
else:
    print(f'Google access granted! {drive_client=}')

try:
    bucket = 'dmheroku'
    bucket_handler = drive_client.get_bucket(bucket)

except  Exception as er:
    print(f'Goggle storage error : {er=} ')
```

And always the same problem:

> https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dmheroku?projection=noAcl:
>   hdrive-167743813226@earnest-command-231305.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>   does not have storage.buckets.get access to dmheroku.')

Comment: Did you verified that the service account that you are using have the required permission?

Answer (score 0):

you should add the permission `storage.buckets.get` to your service account. I suggest you use role `storage.objectViewer` use this command to add the role:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_NAME \
    --role roles/storage.objectViewer \
    --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

Comment: As I  understand gcloud CLI a part of Google Cloud SDK?  So , I don't understand how users have to use HDrive add on Goggle storage feature with Heroku if they don't use Google Cloud? Heroku  returns me two API KEYS ( one json ) and I think that it's enough for control and all operations over Python API's

Comment: Ok, I've installed SDK. PTOJECT_NAME I take from returned from Heroku json , and what about $SERVICE_ACCOUNT?

Comment: it's this one `hdrive-167743813226@earnest-command-231305.iam.gserviceaccount.com`